# .Net Core Minio Client receives error on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3, .net-core, minio

Currently I'm using minio client .net core to store files to Digital Ocean Spaces. I have tested the current implementation on MacOS and the code uploads the file to s3. Once deployed to Ubuntu 16.04, I receiving the error below. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Stack Trace

```
Minio Exception: : Minio.Exceptions.MinioException: MinIO API responded with message=
   at Minio.MinioClient.ParseError(IRestResponse response) in /q/.q/sources/minio-dotnet/Minio/MinioClient.cs:line 381
   at Minio.MinioClient.HandleIfErrorResponse(IRestResponse response, IEnumerable`1 handlers, DateTime startTime) in /q/.q/sources/minio-dotnet/Minio/MinioClient.cs:line 526
   at Minio.MinioClient.<ExecuteTaskAsync>d__84.MoveNext() in /q/.q/sources/minio-dotnet/Minio/MinioClient.cs:line 370
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Minio.MinioClient.<PutObjectAsync>d__20.MoveNext() in /q/.q/sources/minio-dotnet/Minio/ApiEndpoints/ObjectOperations.cs:line 489
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Minio.MinioClient.<PutObjectAsync>d__15.MoveNext() in /q/.q/sources/minio-dotnet/Minio/ApiEndpoints/ObjectOperations.cs:line 254
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Minio.MinioClient.<PutObjectAsync>d__14.MoveNext() in /q/.q/sources/minio-dotnet/Minio/ApiEndpoints/ObjectOperations.cs:line 200
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at CMTZ.Services.S3Service.<uploadS3File>d__8.MoveNext() in /home/rshaw/certified-mixtapes-core/CMTZ.Services/S3Service.cs:line 95
```

Trace

```
- - - - - - - - - - BEGIN REQUEST - - - - - - - - - -

PUT https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/cmtz/UploadedFiles/Mixtapes/test-upload-mixtape-20/cover.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com:443
image/jpeg: System.Byte[]
x-amz-acl: public-read
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-MD5: ****************
x-amz-content-sha256: UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
x-amz-date: 20191104T030850Z
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=*****************/20191104/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-md5;host;x-amz-acl;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=fa6945a220238a7f877fb62d898d5596d9199860455499cec6bedccfb9cae0ed


- - - - - - - - - - END REQUEST - - - - - - - - - -

- - - - - - - - - - BEGIN RESPONSE - - - - - - - - - -

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
x-amz-request-id: tx00000000000000ae68c6c-005dbf9642-334525e-nyc3a
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Mon, 04 Nov 2019 03:08:50 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload
Content-Length: 192
Content-Type: application/xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><RequestId>tx00000000000000ae68c6c-005dbf9642-334525e-nyc3a</RequestId><HostId>334525e-nyc3a-nyc</HostId></Error>

- - - - - - - - - - END RESPONSE - - - - - - - - - -
```

Implementation

```
        public async void uploadS3File(String filePath, String key, string type)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Uploading Object: {filePath}");
            try
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> map = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                map.Add("x-amz-acl", "public-read");
                var minio = new MinioClient(Configuration.S3_HOST_ENDPOINT,
                    Configuration.S3_ACCESS_KEY, Configuration.S3_SECRET_KEY).WithSSL();
                minio.SetTraceOn();

                await minio.PutObjectAsync(Configuration.Bucket,
                                         key, filePath, contentType: type, metaData: map);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Minio Exception: {ex}");

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue above on Linux by upgrading my project target to .net core 2.1. There seem to be an issue with RestSharp. The library was removing the port number in asp.net core 2.0. Make sure to use the RestSharp version dependency in minio-client-dotnet. I upgraded to the latest version and received an error related to signature again when uploading objects with parenthesis and periods in the file name.